# How to remote raspberry pi from putty in Rpi's console mode?

Tags: raspberry-pi, remote-access, putty, raspberry-pi3

Anyone know how to remote to Raspberry Pi 3 console mode from laptop with putty ?
I can remote successfully in Rpi's desktop mode but in console mode I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Raspbian, SSH is disabled by default, so you must create an empty file named 'ssh' on the SD-card.

You can also

```
sudo raspberry-config
```

To enable it through your VNC connection